# how to customize AWS ELB trusted certificate authorities?

Tags: amazon-elb, client-certificates

I want to have a custom "trusted CA" configuration for my API. When not using ELB, I can achieve this by configuring a "ca.pem" file in my web server. However, when using ELB, I think my web server does't receive the original incoming client certificate (but rather the ELB's certificate instead).

Is it possible to somehow make my custom CA take effect even if behind the ELB?

Answer (score 0):

Your instance not only doesn't see the original client's cert... it isn't actually participating in the same TLS session as the client.  ELB Classic and ALB create two independent TLS sessions and tie their payloads together.

To do what you want, the ELB cannot participate in the TLS at all.  It has to be all done by your server, and the balancer has to operate at layer 4 or below. This rules out Application Load Balancer, which operated at only layer 7.

There are two solutions for this.

The old solution was to use an ELB (Classic) in TCP mode, with TLS (SSL) *disabled*.  The ELB blindly passes the payload from the encrypted connections through to the instance, which negotiates TLS directly with the browser, and can thus use its CA file to authenticate the browser.  It gets a little tricky, though, because by default your instance will not see the client's IP address, and because the ELB is running in layer 4 mode (not to mention handling encrypted traffic that it doesn't understand), it can't add `X-Forwarded-For` headers... so have to enable "Proxy protocol" support on the ELB, and your instance has to understand how to extract the client address from the Proxy protocol preamble.

The newer solution is a third type of balancer, called a [Network Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html).  This service operates at layer 3 and allows you to -- essentially -- map a single elastic IP address onto multiple EC2 instances, for balancing incoming requests on specific ports, with health checks to remove unhealthy instances from rotation.  Your instances still are responsible for handling *all* the TLS themselves, but they will see the client address on the incoming connection.